# how do I get the text between <a href> and </a> in php

Tags: php, href, preg-match-all

I have html content with multiple links(a href) , I need to extract the text between the `<a>` tag. 
I have to do it with php.
 
I tried this code :

```
  preg_match_all('/<a\s+href=["\']([^"\']+)["\']/i',$response['content']['html'], $result);
```

This seems to be  not the appropriate solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want the `innerHTML` ?

Comment: maybe you will use **DOM** instead of preg_match DOMDocument::loadHTML

Comment: no ,preg_match_all can do the job, but the regex is not the right one i suppose , for example if i have this :<a href="https://hello.com">text</a> the regex pattern must give me "text " and not the text in a tag (https://hello.com).

Comment: You should *rarely* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: [please don't try to use a regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score -1):

thanks for response , but I found the answer for my question , this works just fine for me , I just changed the regex expression and here is my code:

```
 preg_match_all('#<\s*?a href\b[^>]*>(.*?)</a\b[^>]*>#s',$response['content']['html'], $result);
```